# What is the purpose of returning a reference in overloding =operator

Tags: c++, reference, operator-overloading, operators

I wondered why we should return a reference, when we overload operator `=` (assignment). On the one hand, most of the examples that I've seen (of overloading operator `=`), return a reference, but on the other hand, I saw few examples (of the same subject) that don't return a reference.

Can someone explain me, when we need to return a reference (specifically in operator `=` overloading), and give examples?

Answer (score 5):

The main reason for returning a reference in `operator=` is because the old `Assignable` property for C++03 collection items, required it.

There is a corresponding requirement in C++11.

These requirements stemmed from the built-in `operator=`, which in turn got it from C, where it supported *assignment chaining*, e.g. writing

```
a = b = 666;
```

which is parsed as

```
a = (b = 666);
```

For a user-defined `operator=` it

- is less efficient,
- often more complex (e.g. for an iterator implementation) and
- opens the door to Unholy Practices™ based on side-effects,

and so for a long time, until someone directed my attention to the standard library's requirements, I just defined `operator=` as returning `void`. More efficient, less verbose, no support for bad practices. But with such a requirement – it's yet another bad case of Frozen History™ – one simply must.

Comment: `a = (b = 666);` doesn't require an lvalue/reference to be returned by the assignment. As the previous answer mentioned, it's `(a = b) = 666;` that does.

Comment: @ikegami: right, but it supports it. if you want to get really down to fundamental causes, one may surmise that original C attempted to leverage use of an address already loaded in a register. a value such as 666 might be part of the instruction, not very reusable.

Comment: So the main propose of returning a reference is its' assignment chaining advantage? 
Can you give me also an example when an =operator overloading works without a reference? Thanks!

Comment: @ikegami: For some types, support for chaining (or otherwise using the value) does require a reference. The alternative is to return a copy of the result, and not all types are copyable.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf, It also supports addition, neither of which has to do with the question.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: thanks! i didn't think of that :(. so i was wrong when i said "right" to ikegami. oh well. the nice thing is, learning something means that i'm not old yet, today.

Comment: @guy: you can just define `void operator=( T const& other ) { ... }`. it works nicely, except as item type for standard library container.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf can you give me an example of types that should recieve an reference?

Comment: @Guy, Anything non-trivial, ideally. Saves from making needless copies.

Comment: @Guy: Just searching a bit in the C++11 standard revealed that a deleter object for `unique_ptr` must be `CopyAssignable`, which requires the copy assignment operator to return a reference. A specialization of `shared_ptr` must be `CopyAssignable`. Some operations on `std::vector` require the item type to be `CopyAssignable`. And so on.

Comment: @doc: The optimization you sketch is only possible with machine code inlining of a call, or whole-program global optimization. For an ordinary separately compiled implementation the compiler has no knowledge of whether the result will be used or not. So it must compile a function (such as copy assignment operator) on the assumption that its result will be used.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf yeah, I've deleted comment, because I realized it's wrong. Too much templates recently...

Answer (score 2):

Returning a reference returns a modifiable value (lvalue). It allows the following:

```
(a = b) = c;
```

Ok, that one's a bit silly, but this one makes more sense:

```
++(a = b);
```

Comment: Can you give me also an example when an =operator overloading works without a reference? Thanks! @ikegami

Comment: @Guy, In `x = (y = 4);`, the value returned by the inner assignment doesn't need to be modifiable since nothing writes to it, and the value returned by the outer assignment doesn't need to be modifiable since it's discarded.

Comment: @ikegami I think I've understood, thanks.
One more question/request : 
Can you give me an example which doesn't work without reference?

Comment: @Guy, The two in my answer.

Comment: I'll give you a Perl example that really illustrates the principle. In Perl 5.14+, you can use `$new = $old =~ s/.../.../r;` to perform a substitution on variable `$old` and store the result in `$new`. But before 5.14, substitutions were always done in-place, so you'd have to use the following to get the same effect: `$new = $old; $new =~ s/.../.../;` But since the assignment operator returns an lvalue (reference), you could write that as `($new = $old) =~ s/.../.../;`

Comment: @ikegami And if I creates new class and overload the =operator: Are there any abstract situations in which, I have to return a reference and any abstract situations in which i don't have to?

Comment: There are concrete cases where it's required and not required. What's an abstract case?

Comment: For example, i have a Point class :
class Point
{
 private:
  int _x, _y;
 public:
  Point(int x, int y);
  Point& operator=(const Point& p1);
};
----------------
I this case I use reference, but when I don't need to? 
This is what I've wrote:

Point& Point::operator=(const Point& p2)
{
 _x += p2._x;
 _y += p2._y;

 return *this;
}
@ikegami Thank you so much for your help

Comment: You've already asked in what situations are references needed and in which case they aren't, and these questions were answered. The type of the value doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

One reason is because of efficiency. By passing and returning references in overloading the assignment operator, you prevent a lot of constructors and copy constructors from being called.

Comment: Oh, because it isn't passing by value? Thank you.

Comment: Right. If you pass by value, the function needs to create a copy of whatever you passed in, so it calls a constructor and a copy constructor for that value.